# Junit Hibernate creates database schema multiple times

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, junit

I'm working on a Java Spring+Hibernate project and we have a Junit setup in order to unit-test our code.
The problem I face right now is that I don't understand why Hibernate (with Spring-boot) creates the database schema 2 times before the tests actually run. The sequence is as follows:

1. Alter tables drop all foreign keys
2. Drop tables if exist
3. Create tables
4. Alter tables add constraints (like FK)
5. Alter tables drop all foreign keys
6. Drop tables if exist
7. Create tables
8. Alter tables add constraints
9. Execute all tests

My questions is, if to be more specific: Why points 3-6 including are executed?
Why simply not to execute 1,2,7,8,9. Why do I want this? Because it takes precious time and I don't understand why do I need this.

Below is my persistence configuration:

```
<persistence-unit name="localContainerEntityForTest">
    <description>Spring JPA LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean</description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
        <property name="hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy" value="legacy-jpa"/>
        <property name = "hibernate.show_sql" value = "true" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/myApp?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="hibernate"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Also, below are the annotations I use for every unit test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = JPAConfigurationTestEnviorement.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found, after starting the process to upgrade the spring boot version and I observed some weird code that was not telling me anything before. The reason was the creation of EntityManagerFactory before defining the LocalContainerEntityManagerBean:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
    Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("localContainerEntityForTest");

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lcemfb = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    lcemfb.setPersistenceUnitName("localContainerEntityForTest");
    lcemfb.setPackagesToScan("com.mybasepackage");
    lcemfb.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath:/META-INF/persistence.xml");

    return lcemfb;
}
```

After removing the line:

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("localContainerEntityForTest");
```

the cycle disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly familiar with Hibernate, but less so with Spring Boot.  My guess is that Hibernate is directly responsible for one create-alter-drop cycle and Spring Boot is responsible for the other one.  If you are morally opposed to your current setup, then you can try updating your Hibernate XML to the following:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
```

By choosing the `validate` option, you are instructing Hibernate to only validate your existing schema and to not create or drop any tables.  The trick here is that I'm not sure which of the two cycles you want to remove (nor did you tell us).

Comment: 1. I want the junit to create the database by itself, so create is OK. 2. Spring boot logo is shown just before all 1-9 steps, so I suppose if you are right regarding the cycle responsibility, then these are mixed after the logo being shown. 3. I use validate for the actual application execution (Debug-As, Run-As) 4. Regarding what cycle to remove, depends on 2 here, and also this is what I want to know to differentiate, and exclude, if possible.

Comment: I am out of bullets at the moment, but I'll leave this answer up for a bit in case it inspires someone else to give you a complete answer.